# I was asked to write a function in python(Use the present value of an annuity formula)

Tags: python

Write a function `pay_off_period(PV, PMT, i)` that calculates the minimum number of years left until a loan is fully paid off, if:

the amount owned on the loan is currently equal to PV,
the loan is repaid at an amount, PMT at the END of every YEAR (with the first payment exactly 1 year from now),
at an interest rate of i% per year, compounded annually.

This is what i wrote but i dont get the expected results

```
def pay_off_period(PV, PMT, i):
    n = 0
    PVcal = 0

    while PVcal < PV:

        PVcal *=  (1 + i)
        PVcal += PMT
        n = n + 1

    return n
```

i should be getting this `pay_off_period(1635153, 15000*12, 0.1045) == 30`
but i am getting `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interest is generated on the amount in debt not what you paid in.
And you have to reduce the amount PV to zero in the process of repayment.

Basically you have to calculate every year

```
PV = (PV - PMT)*(1+i)
```

or

```
PV = PV * (1+i) - PMT
```

depending on the definition. Normally it should be the second option.
This would yield the function

```
def pay_off_period(PV, PMT, i):
    n = 0

    while 0 < PV:

        insert the fomula from above
        n = n + 1

    return n
```

Payback time is 20 years respectively 30 years.

Comment: Thank you i am also getting 20 but they say the answer should be exactly 30

Comment: @MRM Using the second formula you should get 30. If this answer helped you, please upvote and if it is the answer you needed mark it as the correct answer (click the tick below the up and downvote arrows). If you need more clarification let me know, but you should probably take the [tour]. Not a bad first question though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pay_off_period(PV, PMT, i):

    year = 0
    while PV>0:

        PV*=(1+i)
        PV -= PMT
        year+=1
    return round(int(year),2)
print(pay_off_period(1635153, 15000*12, 0.1045)==30)
```

Here is the correct answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.